# copy-webpack-plugin v6.0.1: ignore option is not working

Tags: webpack

I have recently updated the copy-webpack-plugin to its latest version. For some reason after following the documentation, I am unable to ignore the file ".gitkeep" This file is not being ignored and always copied to the export folder.

My code:

```
 new CopyWebpack({
            patterns: [
                {
                    from: paths.fonts(),
                    to: paths.output.fonts(),
                    globOptions: {
                        ignore: ['.gitkeep'],
                    },
                },
            ],
        }),

        new CopyWebpack({
            patterns: [
                {
                    from: paths.images(),
                    to: paths.output.images(),
                    globOptions: {
                        ignore: ['.gitkeep'],
                    },
                },
            ],
        }),
```

It's not giving an error at all.

Any idea?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**It's probably a bug in `copy-webpack-plugin` v6.0.1 or in one of its dependencies! 

Downgrade to v5.1.1**

---

If you use a functional version, the following might be the issue:

Set `dot : true,`

```
new CopyWebpack({
            patterns: [
                {
                    from: paths.images(),
                    to: paths.output.images(),
                    globOptions: {
                        dot : true,   // <-- 
                        gitignore: true,
                        ignore: ['.gitkeep'],
                    },
                },
            ],
        }),
```

> If a file or directory path portion has a . as the first character,
>   then it will not match any glob pattern unless that pattern's
>   corresponding path part also has a . as its first character.
>
> For example, the pattern a/.*/c would match the file at a/.b/c.
>   However the pattern a/*/c would not, because * does not start with a
>   dot character.
>
> You can make glob treat dots as normal characters by setting dot:true
>   in the options.

Comment: Can you create a little github repo in order to see what is happening?

Comment: Is this `.gitkeep` in your `paths.images()` folder?

Comment: images: () => path.resolve(module.exports.src(), './images') is the folder i have a file .gitkeep inside the src/images folder which before the latest version was being ignored

Comment: Yeah, I see. This is most certainly a bug.

Comment: @Legenda I am 100% sure it is. Thanks anyways I will accept because the dot has to be set to true. Thanks